# Probability consecutive numbers for unknown # dice

Tags: probability, dice

You're tossing $``n"$ number of dice (all of which are $6$-sided) one at a time.

What's the probability that any $3$ consecutive dice will be $6$?

What's the probability that any $3$ dice are $6$?

I'm having trouble understanding the fundamentals so the difference between the two are unclear to me when solving.

Comment: Let you are throwing die for 5 times. First consecutive case. Let you got 6 three times consecutively and any other number 2 times.

Comment: And in second case out of 5 times you got 6 but not consecutively. For example you got 6,4,6,6,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is clearly equivalent to enumerating the number of $n$ digit sequences with terms in the range $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that no three consecutive sixes exist.

We can find a recursion, Let $a_n$ be the number we want.

We have $a_1=6.a_2=36,a_3=215$.

If $n\geq 3$ we can count the sequences as follows:

There are $5a_{n-1}$ sequences that don't end in $6$. The sequences that end in $6$ can be separated into the $5a_{n-2}$ sequences that don't end in $66$ and the $5a_{n-3}$ sequences that do end in $a_{n-3}$.

So the recursion is $a_n=5(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3})$. You can get a closed form by solving it, but for calculation purposes the recursion will probably be as good, as you can find it in linear time.

Comment: Could this be done with a binomial distribution? I was wondering if one could compact the three consecutive sixes and the rolls before and after these sixes into one event with probability $6^{-3}(1-\frac 16)^2$

Comment: I don't think so, the answer is going to be in terms of the recursive sequence I gave you, and no closed form for it exists. Notice that if you change $3$ with $2$ you get something similar to the fibonacci sequence.

Comment: The other answer was in a more familiar syntax but since it was deleted I assume he's incorrect? I'm having trouble following this but I'll keep trying

Comment: Basically to obtain the answer you first need to build an auciliary sequence $1,6,195,1010,\dots$ such that each term is equal to five times the sum of the previous $3$. If we name these elements $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ we can obtain the answer as follows: The probability that a sequence of $n$ throws contains a sequence of three consecutive sixes is $\frac{6^n-a_n}{6^n}$. Or just $1-\frac{a_n}{6^n}$

Comment: Why is a_3 = 195?

Comment: $6^3-1{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: oh yeah, that was a mistake, should have been $215$